# Passing intent to another android app

Tags: android

I know that another application accepts intent type: vnd.android.cursor.item/postal-address

I can make it show by calling:

```
Uri dataUri = Uri.parse("test");
    Intent intent = new Intent(android.content.Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
 intent.setDataAndType(dataUri, "vnd.android.cursor.item/postal-address");
```

Question is, how to pass well formated address?

E.g. i I pass 
    Uri dataUri = Uri.parse("content://com.android.contacts/data/2057"); 
it works, but I want to pass new address (not from Contacts).

**UPDATE**: This external application has two intent-filters:

intent-filter:
action: 'android.intent.action.MAIN'
category: 'android.intent.category.DEFAULT'
data:
mimeType: 'vnd.android.cursor.item/postal-address'

intent-filter:
action: 'android.intent.action.MAIN'
category: 'android.intent.category.DEFAULT'
data:
mimeType: 'vnd.android.cursor.item/postal-address_V2'
scheme: 'content'
host: 'com.android.contacts'

Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

My observations are the following. This external application in the intent receives the id of the contact. Then it extracts this contact and fetches the postal-address of the contact. Thus, this applications makes a query to contacts content provider and extracts the postal-address by itself. Thus, you should provide this application with the valid url of the contact.

So, I think that this external application requires only url from contacts content provider. You cannot force the application to extract data from other source, unless you don't control this external application.

**UPDATE:** If you want simply show google maps with this address try smth following:

```
Uri geoUri = Uri.parse("geo:0,0?q=your_address");
Intent mapCall = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, geoUri);  
startActivity(mapCall);
```

Comment: Thanks. I think your're right and only way to pass postal-address to this app is to create new temporary contact and pass url of it. Code showing it would be very helpful.
PS. Thanks for code example, but this is not google maps.

Comment: This external application has two intent-filters:

intent-filter:
action: 'android.intent.action.MAIN'
category: 'android.intent.category.DEFAULT'
data:
mimeType: 'vnd.android.cursor.item/postal-address'

intent-filter:
action: 'android.intent.action.MAIN'
category: 'android.intent.category.DEFAULT'
data:
mimeType: 'vnd.android.cursor.item/postal-address_V2'
scheme: 'conent'
host: 'com.android.contacts'

Answer (score 1):

You can pass data by creating a Bundle and adding it to the Intent object, then retrieving the Intent and reading the Bundle data in afterwards. Something like this will create a simple Bundle:

```
Bundle b = new Bundle();
b.putString("address", addressTV.getText().toString()); //can be whatever address string you want
intent.putExtras(b);
```

Comment: I can't control retrieving part. Foreign application only accepts intent mimeType="vnd.android.cursor.item/postal-address" and this is what I want to send. By default Google Maps should open address from such intent, but I don't know how to pass data with such mimeType.

Comment: If you want to just launch Google Maps app you can use an ACTION_VIEW Intent with maps.google.com as the URI like this: `Intent intent = new Intent(android.content.Intent.ACTION_VIEW, 
Uri.parse("http://maps.google.com/maps?saddr=20.344,34.34&daddr=20.5666,45.345"));`